# adding cookie to the cookiemanager using JSR223 sampler is throwing no such method error

Tags: jmeter

I want to add two cookies for the cookie manager but the JSR223 sampler is throwing an error as  Method getCookieManager() not found

import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie;

```
  CookieManager manager = sampler.getCookieManager();
   Cookie cookie = 
new Cookie("CraftSessionId", "${COOKIE_CraftSessionId}", "nginx/1.20.1", "/", false, 0);
Cookie cookie2 = 
new Cookie("CRAFT_CSRF_TOKEN", "${COOKIE_CRAFT_CSRF_TOKEN}", "nginx/1.20.1", "/", false, 0);
 manager.add(cookie);
 manager.add(cookie2);
 log.info("cookieManager::"+manager);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGgXf.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhHZN.png)

Comment: The code will work on the JSR223 Pre-processor within a HTTP request. Ensure you have added a Cookie Manager .

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't have the Cookie Manager in the JSR223 Sampler, if you **really need** to add cookies using scripting - add a [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the HTTP Request sampler and put your "code" there.
2. Replace this `"${COOKIE_CraftSessionId}"` with `vars.get("COOKIE_CraftSessionId")` as by default JMeter will compile and cache only first occurrence of variable, so the first value will be used in all subsequent iterations and it may ruin your test.
3. Do the same for the `COOKIE_CRAFT_CSRF_TOKEN`
4. I don't think you can have `/` in the domain, so it should be just `nginx` and the `1.20.1` should go to the path.
5. You don't need any scripting at all, it's possible to add cookies manually using HTTP Cookie Manager

   [image]

More information:

- [JSR223 Sampler Documentatinon](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)
- [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)